# Make text undetectable in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, text, ocr

I have an image and i want to add some text on it that cannot be detected by text detection programs.
How should i draw the text?I was thinking about changing the lightning or saturation to match the image.

Comment: Have your average developer write it out by hand, unreadable.

Comment: @SombreroChicken i have tried hand writting and it did not work out, i was thinking at drawing lines throughout ALL the image, which i think should confuse it.

Comment: So what's the point of your program? That text is meant to be detected by human only?

Comment: As @SombreroChicken, pointed out, **cursive handwriting** is very difficult for OCR algorithms to process. What you want to do is, **make OCR fail on purpose!** So maybe better read up a little on [OCR](https://www.explainthatstuff.com/how-ocr-works.html) and see how it works. Find the chinks in its armor, maybe.

Comment: You could take a look at some captcha images, this is the exact purpose of the artifacts in each image. To make it readable for humans but undetectable for machines.

Comment: What's the purpose of this?